# Chome extension - is any website detector chrome eextention?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any chrome extention, which will detect  any webste's cms (such: wp/ joonla),  plateform such: php/asp etc.
even help to get any more information.

I need now such type detector.

Comment: You'll need to give a lot more information than that. Why do you need to do this? What do you want to do with the information?

Comment: actually sometimes need website information  for cloning site. aactually sometimes client wants clone site.

Comment: Why do you need an extension to do this?  Cloning a site (I'm trying to think of a good reason for that) should be a one time thing.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/2619912) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two extensions that will detect Javascript libraries or CMS frameworks that are being used by a site:

[Frameworks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/frameworks/jgghnecdoiloelcogfmgjgcacadpaejf)  and [Appspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/appspector/homgcnaoacgigpkkljjjekpignblkeae)

You aren't going to find an extension that shows whether PHP or ASP are used because those are server-side technologies and they don't consistently send anything to the client that would enable an extension to detect with 100% accuracy that they are being used.

Comment: thanks a lot. you also mark my question as right.plz